# How widely accepted is OAuth?

Tags: oauth

How widely supported is OAuth vs. other authentication standards?

This may be something for the community wiki, but I'm gonna ask anyway.

I need to invest in something related to server authentication and there seem to be a few good ones out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OAuth is used mostly as an authorization mechanism whereas OpenId is the widespread authentication protocol.

Let me explain with an example:

`Authentication` :OpenId is used mostly as a substitute for managing user accounts...People hate creating new accounts and remembering passwords for it...so u can use openId for such situations...

`Authorization` :If you want to give access to a third party application like lets say another website twitterWithSoccerUI.com....which tweets for you...except it has soccerposter UI....in that case u need to authorize twitterWithSoccerUI.com to tweet on your behalf...

Here's a list...

> 1. Google -> Oauth(For authorization) + OpenId(For authentication)
> 2. Facebook -> OAuth 2.0
> 3. Twitter -> OAuth 1.0a
> 4. Yahoo -> OpenId
> 5. StackExchange -> OpenId

Feel free to add more..

Comment: Well, then that begs the question.  What is the strict difference between authentication and authorization beyond "Who you are" and "yes, you can have access to my stuff" ?

Answer (score 2):

**OAuth** is an authentication protocol that allows users to approve application to act on their behalf without sharing their password. More information can be found at [oauth.net](http://oauth.net/) or in the excellent [Beginner's Guide to OAuth from Hueniverse.](http://hueniverse.com/oauth/)

[More on twitter development blog](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_faq)